# Spring JPA: same operand for 2 conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

In Spring JPA Repository if we name method like:

```
Entity findByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastName, String firstName);
```

then we get query like:

```
… where x.lastname = ?1 or x.firstname = ?2
```

Can I named method somehow to get query like:

```
… where x.lastname = ?1 or x.firstname = ?1
```

I mean something else than just passing same string to both arguments. (i.e. `findByLastnameOrFirstname("John", "John")`)

Comment: I don't know if you can achieve your purpose just with the method name. An alternative solution is using @Query annotation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: @RubioRic yes, of course, I already did it with `@Query`, but I'm looking for more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

> Can I named method somehow to get query like:

```
… where x.lastname = ?1 or x.firstname = ?1
```

No, this is possible. You need to use other approaches as for e.g. `@Query` annotations.